# Adding references not working because the project targets .NET Core while file reference targets .NET framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am new to Windows Metro app and I'm recently involved in building an app that sends mails with attachments. When I try to add a reference to the project, an error is displayed:

`The project targets .NET Core while the file reference targets .NET Framework.`

Is there any way to remove this error?

Answer (score 2):

A Metro style app must use references to another .NETCore or Portable Library binary only...
It can not reference a full .NET library because the Metro profile is not that large (and would fail store certification).

You will have to create a portable version of the library you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a normal Windows Application type project. For this Application type you have to reference DLLs from .NetFramework folder instead of .NETCore folder.